# Nginx Cache By Pass for Query String

Tags: nginx

What's the best way to exclude a certain query string argument from being cached.

I have a location /news/ where I want /news/xyz to be cached but not /news/xyz?view_story=2022.

I have tried the following:

```
fastcgi_cache_bypass $arg_view_story;
fastcgi_no_cache $arg_view_story;
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work.

I have also tried calling Cache configuration only for URLs without query strings but it doesn't work either.

```
location ~ ^/news/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ {

## called Cache configuration 
  
    }
```

Appreciate any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

All you need is two lines:

```
fastcgi_cache_bypass $is_args;
fastcgi_no_cache $is_args;
```

Hope this helps anyone else.